# JobScheduler and the JobIntentService

Tags: android

So I currently use the `JobScheduler` to schedule jobs based on various conditions and I was thinking I would want to execute them using the `JobIntentService`. However, I see that the `JobIntentService` also has a `enqueueWork()` method. Is this a replacement for the `JobScheduler`? Is it optional so I can ignore it and just use the `JobScheduler` to schedule the tasks and let the `JobIntentService` only worry about execution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `JobScheduler` for running `JobIntentService`?
According to the official doc, JobIntentService `will be subject to standard JobScheduler policies for a Job with a setOverrideDeadline(long) of 0` and you can not apply other `JobScheduler's` options to it.
You have to run it using it's own `enqueueWork` method,

```
enqueueWork(applicationContext, Intent(applicationContext, MyJobIntentService::class.java))
```

Your service can be developed this way:

```
class MyJobIntentService : JobIntentService() {
    val TAG = "TAG_MyJobIntentService"
    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        // do your work here
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing work: " + intent)
    }
    companion object {
        internal val JOB_ID = 1000

        internal fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent) {
            JobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService::class.java, JOB_ID, work)
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to put it to your manifest

```
<service
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
     android:exported="false"
     android:name=".MyJobIntentService">
</service>
```

Comment: What should we use if we have a network task(Should be in background task) and we have to make them trigger only in a certain situation as JobDispatcher do?

Comment: I would suggest you to use JobService if you use android 5+, or firebaseJobDispatcher if you want to support old devices.